# tclmagick load error

Tags: dll, imagemagick, tcl, msvcrt

I try to call in a Tcl script:

```
load tclmagick.dll
```

and get

```
couldn't load library "TclMagick.dll": invalid argument
```

I've tried the Dependency Walker, which tells me that the msvcrt.exe doesn't export a function named "__adjust_fdiv". However, I have no clue how to fix that. Any advice?

OS: Windows 7, 64bit
packages: TclMagick and ImageMagick

Comment: Excellent question. Could you add what `parray tcl_platform` reports to your question, and also say where you got your Tcl installation from? Thanks!

Comment: tcl_platform(byteOrder)   = littleEndian
tcl_platform(machine)     = intel
tcl_platform(os)          = Windows NT
tcl_platform(osVersion)   = 6.1
tcl_platform(platform)    = windows
tcl_platform(pointerSize) = 4
tcl_platform(threaded)    = 1
tcl_platform(user)        = michir
tcl_platform(wordSize)    = 4

Comment: The Tcl installation is from AktiveState

Comment: I suppose it's `msvcrt.dll` which doesn't export `__adjust_fdiv`, right? Could you copy and paste its file version? (Available in the Properties dialog of the Windows Explorer context menu on a DLL file.)

Comment: Also, are you using 32-bit installation of ActiveState Tcl? I'm not sure 64-bit Windows 7 ships a 64-bit version of `msvcrt.dll` (that is, without any integer suffix like in `msvcr80.dll`), but if it does I would not be surprised to not see `__adjust_fdiv` in it as this code related to messing with FP operations of older Pentiums from 90-s. So you might need to seek for 32-bit `msvcrt.dll` (under `C:\Windows\SysWOW64` supposedly).

Comment: I use the 32-bit version of ActiveState Tcl (in fact I have them both installed). I will check out the msvcrt.dll

Comment: I found two msvcrt.dll: in system32 (620kB, 64bit) and in SysWOW64 (674kB, 32bit) both version 7.0.7601.17744; the 32bit version has the "__adjust_fdiv" in the export list the 64bit version doesn't have it

Comment: @DonalFellows do you have any ideas in the light of these new upates? My own C-fu is unfortunately lacking to help the OP further :-(